# Minimax algorithm for connect 4

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evaluation, minimax

I've been trying to implement minimax algorithm in connect 4 but I encountered a problem
that there are only two values to evaluate moves : infinity for winning game and -infinity for the opposite , and I need a huge deep to reach these values on the first moves , so what I need is an evaluation function but I don't have any idea how should it be ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Connect 4 also allows for a draw, so you have three possible outcomes.
Second, why would you use +inf and -inf when you can use +1 and -1?
Third, the obvious starting place for a board evaluation function would be "number of tokens in a line."

But that is only a starting point.

Comment: OK you are right but how should I evaluate neutral moves and what values can I give them if they are only between 1 and -1

Comment: You're allowed to use floats or even doubles, not just ints. Or if you really want to use ints, widen the range up a little.  You're also allowed to experiment a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

A good Evaluation function for the game *Connect Four* would analyze the threats of both players. The article [*Expert Play in Connect-Four*](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/c4.html) from *James D. Allen* is a great source for studying and analyzing the game. To get a clue on how to create a evaluation function read the chapter *Threat Analysis* carefully.

Good Luck!